# how to add android native libraries into one aar

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, aar

I am creating private Sdk for enduser.I face some problems in my project.

1. Add multiple aar/libraries into one aar file.
2. Add native libraries like appcompactv7, RecyclerView etc.. into final aar.
3. Some jar file into lib folder.

For Example:
Library project1:lib1

Library project2:lib2 -> lib2 have 2 jar file (okhhttp,retrofit)

My First Lib1 build.gradle structure:

```
compile 'some_library_hosted_on_maven'
```

My Second Lib2 build structure:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile project(':lib1')
```

Now I want to deploy/upload only one aar file for end user.

for creating one aar file I already go thorough [fat-aar.gradle](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar). But i can't resolve my problem. Kindly help if anyone face or experience this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing and that you cannot resolve?

Comment: Developers using your library need to be able to use different-but-compatible versions of dependencies like the `com.android.support` ones, such as to integrate security fixes. Your plan to "to deploy/upload only one aar file" will prevent that.

Comment: You could upload your library in a maven repository (private or public).

Comment: @jaibatrik basically my library use com.android.support.libraries and resources, so i want to create and deploy only one aar to enduser. Because this library not only use for android, I want to distribute this library on multi-platform like unity, cocos2d and other engine.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes, I will upload my library in maven repository, when i complete it. [merged multiple aar and jar file into one]